# Critical Wrapper Issue

Tags: css, width, containers, wrapper, margins

I  know this must be a very simple and easy to solve issue but i don't know as i am new to programming.

I am using a default height of 300px but as more and more content is being added, instead of the wrapper expanding to fit the content, the content is going out of the content. And then i have a second container to the right side of the this wrapper which also drags down if the wrapper will expand to fit in the content.    How can i fix this?

wrapper:

```
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
      margin:0 auto; 
       height: 300px;
        width:60%;
     font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      border:0px solid #FFFFFF;
       margin-top:25px;
       font-size:15px;
      color: #222222;
      margin-left:60px;
```

container1:

```
         background-color: #000000;
                margin:0 auto; 
                  height: 80px;
             width:20%;
                   border:0px solid #FFFFFF;
                  margin-top:25px;
                  font-size:15px;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                margin-left: 70%;
               margin-top:-317px;
```

div#wrapper:

```
                   <?php echo $userposts;?>
```

div#container1:
                              
                              Add a post
                              Add a picture

Update:

I fixed it by replacing the the position of the divs in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you set height of an element, then this element will always have this height. You can change the behavior of the element when overflowed by adding overflow:hidden or overflow:hide.  However as far as I understand what you actually want is to set a minimal height. So instead of height:300px put min-height:300px this will ensure that when content of the wrapper exceeds 300px, wrapper will grow together with it's content.

Comment: That does it but the container1 issue remains.  As soon as the wrapper is changing the height to contain the content the container1 drags down.   Thanks

Comment: In other words how can i make the container1's position fixed so regardless if content is present or not it stays put.  I have tried position: fixed and various other positions.  doesn't work

Comment: to figure out why contentainer1 drags down we will need some html code as well.

Comment: And where is the container1 element in your html example? It would be nice to see the whole html structure.

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying a fixed height, so of course your div won't grow and the content flows out. Don't set the height. Or if you need a minimum height, set the minimum-height property instead. (Note that IE6 and earlier ignore this property, though, so for them you have to set the [height property instead](http://sandgroper14.wordpress.com/2007/05/24/css-min-height-issue-solved/).)